# Модульный тест класса

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

при написании модульного теста возникает ошибка "object не содержит определения для qwerty"

код библиотечной функции

```
namespace ClassKatet 
{
    public static class Katet {

    /// <param name="c"></param>
    /// <param name="a"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static double qwerty(double c, double a) 
    {
      return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(c, 2) - Math.Pow(a, 2));
    }
  }
}
```

код модульного теста

```
namespace UnitTestProject3
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private int actual;


        public object Katet { get; private set; }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            // arrange
            int c = 9;
            int a = 5;
            int result = 7;

            // act

            var actual = Katet.qwerty(c, a);

            // assert
            Assert.AreEqual(result, actual);

        }
    }
}
```

как исправить?

Comment: А почему у вас все статическое?

Comment: `public object Katet` что это и зачем оно тут?

Comment: мне кажется человек вообще слабо понимает чего тут накалякал)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите эту строчку

```
public object Katet { get; private set; }
```

У вас же класс статический, зачем вам экземпляр, который вы даже не инициализируете, и тем более храните как `object` - естественно `object` ничего не знает об методе `qwerty`. И вообще равен null

Comment: public object Katet { get; private set; } это то что предлагает VS, т.к. не видет класс Katet

Comment: понятно что он его не видит. Добавьте в проект с тестами ваш проект в котором находится класс

Comment: он находится в одном проекте

Comment: ну тогда либо напишите полностью ClassKatet.Katet либо поместите неймспейс ClassKatet  в using в начале файла с тестами.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, помогло добавление ссылки на класс к тесту и добавление using!